# How can I run two bash scripts simultaneously and without repetition of the same action?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, scripting

I'm trying to write a script that automatically runs a data analysis program.  The data analysis takes a file, analyzes it, and puts all the outputs into a folder.  The program can be run on two terminals simultaneously (each analyzing a different subject file).

I wrote a script that can do all the inputs automatically.  However, I can only get my script to run one automatically.  If I run my script simultaneously it will analyze the same subject twice (useless)

Currently, my script looks like:

```
for name in `ls [file_directory]`
do

    [Data analysis commands]

done
```

If you run this on two terminals, it will start from the top of the directory containing all the data files.  This is a problem, so I tried to do checks for duplicates but they weren't very effective.

I tried a name comparison with the if command (didn't work because all the output files except one were of a unique name, so it would check the first outfput folder at the top of the directory and say the name was different even though an output folder further down had the same name).  It looked something like..

```
for name in `ls <file_directory>`
do
     for output in `ls <output directory>`  
     do
          If [ name==output ]
          then
               echo "This file has already been analyzed."
          else
               <Data analyis commands>
          fi
     done
done
```

I thought this was the right method but apparently not.  I would need to check all the names before some decision was made (rather one by one which that does)

Then I tried moving completed data files with the mv command (didn't work because "name" in the for statement stored all the file names so it went down the list regardless of what was in the folder at present).  I remember reading something about how shell scripts do not do things in "real time" so it makes sense that this didn't work.

My thought was looking for some sort of modification to that if statement so it does all the name checks before I make a decision (how?)

Also are there any other commands I could possibly be missing that I could possibly try?

Comment: Why not *background* each different search process? e.g. `( your specific dir cmd)&` and go to the next? Also there is Gnu `parallel`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I wish `parallel` natively existed on `OS X` ...

Comment: @I'L'I **GNU Parallel** is simple to install with `brew install parallel` - and indispensable!

Answer (score 0):

One pattern I use often is to use split command.

```
ls <file_directory> > file_list
split -d -l 10 file_list file_list_part
```

This will create files like file_list_part00 to file_list_partnn
You can then feed these file names to you script.

```
for file_part in `ls file_list_part*`
do
   for file_name in `cat file_part | tr '\n' ' '`
   do
     data_analysis_command file_name
   done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use "ls" in a "for" (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

I think you should use a fifo (see mkfifo)

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-on from the comments, you can install **GNU Parallel** with [homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
brew install parallel
```

Then your command becomes:

```
parallel analyse ::: *.dat
```

and it will process all your files in parallel using as many CPU cores as you have in your Mac. You can also add in:

```
parallel --dry-run analyse ::: *.dat
```

to get it to show you the commands it would run without actually running anything.

You can also add in `--eta` (Estimated Time of Arrival) for an estimate of when the jobs will be done, and `-j 8` if you want to run, say 8, jobs at a time. Of course, if you specifically want the 2 jobs at a time you asked for, use `-j 2`.

You can also have **GNU Parallel** simply distribute jobs and data to any other machines you may have available via `ssh` access.